# Adding YouTube Video to Photo Gallery

Tags: html, css, youtube

I have a photo gallery here: https://www.metaldepotinc.com/gallery.aspx but would like an option for when someone clicks on a thumbnail of a YouTube video it will expand like the pictures do. Is this even possible? Here is the coding:

```js
   function myFunction(imgs) {
        var expandImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
        var imgText = document.getElementById("imgtext");
        expandImg.src = imgs.src;
        imgText.innerHTML = imgs.alt;
        expandImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
      }
```

```css
      * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }

      body {
        margin: 0;
        font-family: Arial;
      }

      /* The grid: Four equal columns that floats next to each other */
      .column {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        padding: 5px;
      }

      /* Style the images inside the grid */
      .column img {
        opacity: 0.8; 
        cursor: pointer; 
      }

      .column img:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }

      /* Clear floats after the columns */
      .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
      }

      /* The expanding image container */
      .container {
        position: relative;
        display: none;
      }

      /* Expanding image text */
      #imgtext {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 15px;
        left: 15px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 20px;
      }

      /* Closable button inside the expanded image */
      .closebtn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 15px;
        color: white;
        font-size: 35px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <h2>Updike Barndominium</h2>
      <p>Click on the images below to enlarge:</p>
    </div>
    <!-- The 5 columns -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <img src="Updike1.jpg" alt="Updike Barndominium" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="Updike2.jpg" alt="Updike Barndominium" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="Updike3.jpg" alt="Updike Barndominium" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="Updike4.jpg" alt="Updike Barndominium" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <img src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4g3FfxkYvGQ" alt="" style="width:100%" onclick="myFunction(this);">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>
      <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">
      <div id="imgtext"></div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: One alternate solution is that use a thumbnail image for your YouTube video in the image listing area and when it is clicked open YouTube iframe below it

Comment: I thought about that but I don't know how to make an iframe open below it. Thanks for the response! @ZakiMohammed

Comment: You need to use an iframe to load resources from an external source. @ZakiMohammed 's idea is good and recommended, and if you add a lazy-load on this videos it will be tones better (to not start loading iframes if the user aren't asking for them, or said with another words, load on demand with javascript)